# A corollary of Cayley's Theorem pertaining to automorphisms

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, automorphism-group

I made a rather interesting observation. For a finite group $G$, by Cayley's Theorem, there is a natural embedding (actually many possible such embeddings, but any one of the natural ones that arise in the proof of the theorem will do for the rest of this argument), of $G$ in the symmetric group $S_n$, where $|G|=n$. Consider the *left* multiplication map (the *right* map could be used instead, WLOG) for $G$, and in particular, note that this is one way of explicitly realizing $G$ as a subgroup of the $S_n$ (where we view $S_n$ as the $\text{Sym}(G)$, the group of permutations of the elements of $G$). Now consider any $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(G)$. We remark that this too can be considered as a permutation on the elements of $G$, and examine how they relate to the permutations given by the left multiplication map. The homomorphism property guarantees that it must commute with the left multiplication map, for it should not matter if first apply the automorphism and then operate within the group, or do those things in opposite order. Moreover the reverse is *also* true, any permutation on the elements of $G$ which commutes with the left multiplication map must also satisfy the homomorphism property and is, in particular, also a bijection on the elements of $G$ and thus an automorphism. Therefore, we can describe $\text{Aut}(G)$ in terms of centralizers in $\text{Sym}(G)$ as follows (with some slight abuse of notation):

$$\text{Aut}(G)\simeq C_{\text{Sym}(G)}(G)$$

I have not encountered this particular characterization before, and it seems like it may be useful in certain situations (and might suggest some fairly efficient ways to compute automorphism groups via permutation representations). Is this known? And if so, what are some of its ramifications?

Comment: So this doesn't work because commutation with left multiplication action would be $\sigma (g(x))=g(\sigma (x))$ when the homomorphism property is $\sigma (g(x))=\sigma (g)(\sigma (x))$?

Comment: This is covered in Marshall Hall Jr.s textbook on the theory of groups, page 83. Theorem 6.3.1 is that the centralizer of the left regular rep is the right regular rep, and vice versa. Theorem 6.3.2 is that the subgroup of the normalizer fixing the identity element (using the regular representation) is the automorphism group.

Comment: Computationally: Computing normalizers and centralizers in permutation groups have bad theoretical complexity, and while usually fairly quick, sometimes take a long time in practice. Another issue is that we'd like algorithms to run in time polynomial in $\log|G|$, but even writing down the regular representation takes exponential time, $|G|$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt If you want to compute the normalizer in ${\rm Sym}(G)$ of $G$, then it is generally much more efficient to compute ${\rm Aut}(G)$ and then construct the associated semidirect product directly. For groups $G$ that are not too big (perhaps up to order $10^4$ or $10^5$), this representation of the holomorph can be very convenient for various caculaltions, such as testing for conjugacy of subgroups of $G$ under ${\rm Aut}(G)$.

Comment: But computing centralizers of permutation groups in the symmetric group is generally fast - i.e. polynomial time.

Comment: I thought the theoretical runtime of centralizers in permutation groups was still unknown, and had some important consequences if it was polynomial? Cheryl Praeger said in 2019: "No polynomial time algorithm is known for computing intersections, centralizers or normalizers of subgroups in permutation groups.  The current generic state of the art algorithm to search for such subgroups of a given permutation group is called partition backtrack."

Comment: Ah, I see. The difference is normalizer or centralizer in Sym versus a generic permutation group

Comment: Yes, centralizers in the symmetric group are polynomial-time. But normalizers in the symmetric group are generally believed to be of the same complexity as normalizers in general, and at least as bad as intersections and general centralizers (which are polynomially equivalent).

Comment: Thanks! $~~~~~$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not true that ${\rm Aut}(G) \cong C_{{\rm Sym}(G)}(G)$ - in fact $C_{{\rm Sym}(G)}(G) \cong G$ (and it is equal to $G$ iff $G$ is abelian).

We have ${\rm Aut}(G) \cong N_{{\rm Sym}(G)}(G)_{1}$ i.e. the stabilizer of the identity element in the normalizer in ${\rm Sym}(G)$ of $G$.

The full normalizer $N_{{\rm Sym}(G)}(G)$ is isomorphic to the semidirect product $G \rtimes_\phi {\rm Aut}(G)$ (with $\phi$ equal to the identity map on ${\rm Aut}(G)$), which is known as the *holomorph* of $G$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\text{Sym}(\Omega)$?

Comment: The symmetric group on the set $\Omega$.